# a issue about python socket

Tags: python, sockets

I have finished a python socket server script. and I  want to connect to it  through browser,and then the socket server will send some data to the browser which will display the data message. 
  the server socket can accept the request from browser, but the server can not send data message to browser, the browser is in blocking status for a long time. why?
  the server socket script is as following, please help me to review this code,thanks!

```
import socket 

HOST='127.0.0.1' 
PORT=9003 
BUFFER=4096 
sock=socket.socket(socket.AF_INET,socket.SOCK_STREAM)

sock.bind((HOST,PORT)) 

sock.listen(0) 
print('tcpServer listen at: %s:%s\n\r' %(HOST,PORT)) 
while True: 
  client_sock,client_addr=sock.accept() 
  print('%s:%s connect' %client_addr) 
  while True: 
    recv=client_sock.recv(BUFFER) 
    if not recv: 
      client_sock.close() 
      break 
    print('[Client %s:%s said]:%s' % (client_addr[0],client_addr[1],recv)) 
    client_sock.send('HTTP/1.1 200 OK \n Content-type:text/html\r\n\r\n tcpServer has received your message') 
sock.close()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need to close the `client_sock` after sending back the response

```
import socket 

HOST='127.0.0.1' 
PORT=9003 
BUFFER=4096 
sock=socket.socket(socket.AF_INET,socket.SOCK_STREAM)

sock.bind((HOST,PORT)) 

sock.listen(0) 
print('tcpServer listen at: %s:%s\n\r' %(HOST,PORT)) 
while True: 
  client_sock,client_addr=sock.accept() 
  print('%s:%s connect' %client_addr) 
  recv=client_sock.recv(BUFFER) 
  if not recv: 
    client_sock.close() 
    break 
  print('[Client %s:%s said]:%s' % (client_addr[0],client_addr[1],recv)) 
  client_sock.send('HTTP/1.1 200 OK \n Content-type:text/html\r\n\r\n tcpServer has received your message') 
  client_sock.close()
sock.close()
```

Note that this also means that you need to go straight to waiting for another connection, so I've removed the inner loop from your code.